# Force Emmet (VS Code) to wrap all abbreviations inline

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I often wrap parts of my HTML text inside tags using [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

The command is "`Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`" (Alt+Shift+W on Windows).

It it possible to force Emmet to wrap all my selection inline, i.e. on the same line?

See example below, where a `<p>` tag automatically puts my selection on a new line, and a `<span>` tag just wraps my selection in the same line.

I would like all wrap-with-abbreviations to behave like the `<span` example.

[image: Animated example of questioned behaviour in VSCode]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your settings:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "html": {
     "tag_nl": false
  }
}
```

`tag_nl`:

> output each tag on new line with indentation, boolean. Values are true
>   (each tag on new line), false (no formatting) and 'decide' (string;
>   only block-level elements on new lines).

See [emmet doc on syntax profiles](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/) and [vscode emmet config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration)

This will do what you want but it appears to apply to all emmet expansions, not just wraps.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you kindly!