# VS Code - how to disable new line while closing html tags

Tags: visual-studio-code

Silly question but it constantly slowing me down,
In VS Code when I create div and press enter , it looks like that:

```
<div>
    |
</div>
```

with new line and cursor in between.
It really doesn't help me in my workflow, since I find myself most of the time using shift+ctrl+arrow to move things around in html files and always deleting this line.
Editor should be a helpful tool, how do I disable this?
I've tried adding: 
*"html.format.contentUnformatted": "div",*
and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.  Do you have prettier or similar installed?  Disable formatter extension and see if it still happens.

Comment: That's weird, I checked settings and extension, I don't have any formatter installed or any suspicious configuration.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390142/force-emmet-vs-code-to-wrap-all-abbreviations-inline/53400223#53400223

Comment: Did you solve it?