# Is there a built-in way to wrap a text with a dynamic wrapper?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to:

- select a `text`;
- hit a key-binding;
- write, e.g., `TAG`;
- hit return;
- get `opening.TAG{text}closing.TAG` as a typed result.

Is there a built-in way? Or...
anyone willing to explain me how to program this? :-)

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390142/force-emmet-vs-code-to-wrap-all-abbreviations-inline/53400223#53400223 and especially the emmet `wrap` commands.  The link shows how to avoid the tag being wrapped with newlines.

Comment: @Mark: Thank you so much!